# Javascript array mixed with json not working as intended

Tags: javascript, json

I have this piece of code, but whenever I run **findTimeSlots()** it immediately messes up my global array **apptData** but I don't see in anywhere in this function that is supposed to have changed it.

(ConsoleLog)

```
(index):69 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {service: "A, B", duration: 50, tech: "C"}
1: {service: "B", duration: 30, tech: "C"}
2: {service: "A, D", duration: 60, tech: "A"}
3: {service: "D", duration: 40, tech: "A"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
(index):45 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {service: "A, B", duration: 50, tech: "C"}
1: {service: "B", duration: 30, tech: "C"}
2: {service: "A, D", duration: 60, tech: "A"}
3: {service: "D", duration: 40, tech: "A"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
var apptData = [];
function addApptData(serviceName, rawDuration, selectedTech){
    apptData.push({
        'service': serviceName,
        'duration': rawDuration,
        'tech' : selectedTech
    })
}
function reduceApptData(index){
    apptData.splice(index, 1);
}
function findTimeSlots(dateStr){
    console.log(apptData);             //* Index 45 *//
    var final = new Array();
    var service, duration;
    for(var i = 0; i < apptData.length; i++){
        var duplicated = false;
        for(var j = 0; j < final.length; j++){
            if(final[j].tech == apptData[i].tech){
                service = ", "+apptData[i].service;
                final[j].service += service;
                duration = apptData[i].duration;
                final[j].duration += duration;
                duplicated = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!duplicated){
            final.push(apptData[i]);
        }
    }
 }
addApptData("A", 20, "C");
addApptData("B", 30, "C");
addApptData("A", 20, "A");
addApptData("D", 40, "A");
console.log(apptData);                //* Index 69 *//
// If I remove the line below, I get the expected result, when I try to 
// run with this line it will mess up apptData[]
findTimeSlots("");
```

What I expected to be is

```
0: {service: "A", duration: 20, tech: "C"}
1: {service: "B", duration: 30, tech: "C"}
2: {service: "A", duration: 20, tech: "A"}
3: {service: "D", duration: 40, tech: "A"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So basically I expect it to remain the same.

I wanted to consolidate my **var apptData** into my **var final** inside my **findTimeSlots()**

After debugging, I found out that my **apptData** keep changing unexpectedly for some reason.

I suspect this to be very trivial but I cannot for the life of me figure out.

Comment: That's why I love FP and it's immutability.

Comment: `final.push(apptData[i])` pushes an object without copying it, `final[j].service += service;` and `final[j].duration += duration;` modify objects that were pushed.

Comment: When you assign objects in JavaScript you're not making a copy, you're just assigning a reference to the same object. So when `findTimeSlots()` modifies `final[j].property`, it's also modifying `apptData`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object for ways to clone a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

You should make a shallow copy of apptData.

One thing you should take note of JavaScript is the difference between assignment by value vs assingment by reference.

When primitive data types such as numbers(i.e. 2, 23), strings (i.e 'aaa', '123') are assigned to a variable, the variable contains the primitive value.

On the other hand, when non-primitive data types (arrays, objects, functions) are assigned to a variable, the variable contains the reference (which 'points' to the object's location on the memory), rather than the value itself.

To answer your question, you should be making a shallow copy of `apptData`, rather than making a direct reference to it.

Assuming that your apptData is an array of (non-nested) objects, here is a simply way to make a shallow copy of it using ES6's spread syntax:

```
const apptDataCopy = apptData.map(serviceObject => ({...serviceObject}));
```

From there, you can make any changes you wish to `apptDataCopy`, and it will not affect the original `apptData`.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is explained in this tiny example:

```js
let a = {test: 10};
let b = a;
b.text = 11;
console.log(a); //this will print {test: 11}
```

Since `a` is an object, when you assign `let b = a;` you are actually saving a reference to `a`, not cloning `a`.

You need to clone the object `apptData[i]`, and to do that [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344074/7021694)

So instead of `final.push(apptData[i]);` you should push a cloned `apptData[i]`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
var apptData = [], typeSelectedTech = new Set(), finalData =[], tmpObj = {serviceName: '', rawDuration: 0}
const addApptData = (serviceName, rawDuration, selectedTech)=> {
    apptData.push({
        serviceName,
        rawDuration,
        selectedTech
    })
    if (typeSelectedTech.has(selectedTech)) {
      finalData.push({serviceName: tmpObj.selectedTech + ',' + serviceName, rawDuration: tmpObj.rawDuration + rawDuration, selectedTech})
    }else {
      tmpObj = {
          serviceName,
          rawDuration,
          selectedTech
      }
      typeSelectedTech.add(selectedTech)

    }
}

addApptData("A", 20, "C");
addApptData("B", 30, "C");
addApptData("A", 20, "A");
addApptData("D", 40, "A");
console.log(finalData);
console.log(apptData);
```

First of all, I believe that you have solved the problem, my answer is only for communication.

I tried the rewriting method, you can get the raw data and the target data. Although it produces multiple global variables, I can't think of other ways.

So as a communication, I hope other people can have a better way.